# Get custom date format regular expression

Tags: python, python-re

I want to get the custom date format from a log file that contains multiple lines, with some help I was able to get the output `WorkerThreads = 50` which is the highest number from all the lines that match the criteria of the RE `pattern = r'Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" .* WorkerThreads="(\d+)"'` and I need the custom date format from the same line too

```
    Line 3072: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:20:16 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="18" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="42" 
    Line 3329: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:21:17 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="1" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="42" 
    Line 3586: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:22:17 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="1" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="22" 
    Line 3843: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:23:17 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="50" 
    Line 4100: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:24:17 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="8" 
    Line 4357: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:25:17 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="6" 
    Line 4614: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:26:18 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="4" 
    Line 4871: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:27:18 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="1" 
    Line 5128: 10000 2aa0  04/04 17:28:18 ### Context="cvd.exe" Module="ThreadPool" Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" BusyThreads="0" MaxThreads="600" ReadyTask="0" TaskList="0" WorkerThreads="1"
```

I'm having trouble getting the output `04/04 17:23:17 WorkerThreads = 50`since I am not very familiar with regular expressions. Here is what I have that gets the highest number of multiple lines from multiple log files

```
pattern = r'Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" .* WorkerThreads="(\d+)"'
worker_threads = []
path = "C:/"
log_pattern = 'PerformanceMetrics*.log'

files = os.listdir('C:/Logs/')
match_file = fnmatch.filter(files, log_pattern)
print(match_file)

for log_file in match_file:
    with open(path + log_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            match = re.search(pattern, line)
            if match:
                worker_threads.append(int(match.group(1)))
        print("WorkerThreads =", max(worker_threads))
        worker_threads = []
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part of the problem are you having trouble with?  Perhaps you need to do a little studying of regex basics, or the reference docs for the regex you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the date as well:

```python
from operator import itemgetter
import re

log_file = ...

with open(log_file) as f:
    pattern = r'  (.+) ###.+Instance="sLNSQLServer61" Type="SnapShot" .* WorkerThreads="(\d+)"'
    matches = re.findall(pattern, f.read())
    matches = [(d, int(w)) for d, w in matches]
    matches = sorted(matches, key=itemgetter(1))
    print(f"{matches[-1][0]} WorkerThreads = {matches[-1][1]}")
```